# Laravel 5.8 : __construct() must be of the type integer, array given

Tags: php, html, laravel

hi i have a problem with form in laravel 5.8. When i send form i have this error

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR)
>   Argument 2 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse::__construct() must be of the type integer, array given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\transport\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Redirector.php on line 203

My controller:

```
public function zawies(Request $request, $id)
{
    $zawies = \App\Przedsiebiorca::findOrFail($request->id);

    $input = Input::all();
    $id = Input::get('idz');

    $zawies_lic = DB::table('dok_przed')->where('nr_dok', $request->nr_dok)->get();

    foreach($zawies_lic as $li){
        $li->id;
        $li->id_przed;
    }

    $powod = Input::get('powod');
    $dat_zaw = Input::get('dat_zaw');
    $dat_zaw_do = Input::get('dat_zaw_do');
    $dat_zaw_new = Carbon::createFromDate($dat_zaw)->addYear()->format('Y-m-d');
    $lic = \App\DokumentyPrzed::findOrFail($li->id);


    $lic->update(['status'=>'2','dat_zaw'=> $dat_zaw_new,'dat_zaw_do'=> $dat_zaw_do,'powod'=>$powod]);
    Alert::warning('Zawieszono licencję/zezwolenie przedsiębiorcy', '');
    return redirect('/przedsiebiorca', compact('zawies_lic'))->with('lic');
}
```

Here is my app: http://tr.page4me.pl./przedsiebiorca

When you click yellows icon show you form with dates fields. After click button 'Zawieś' here shows an error. But as I refresh the page, the form will execute the command correctly and correctly add data to the database despite the error shown above. What I'm doing wrong is showing this error.

Comment: you can not redirect and use with, redirect is a 302 redirect, but if you want to change it you can pass as second argument the code you want, not an array, as the error mention

Comment: Check the docs for redirect here https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-redirect

Comment: thx for help.:) i change only redirect -> on this: return redirect('/przedsiebiorca');